# FreeFontPath: FPE "unix/:7100" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing

Tags: xvfb

I tried to run Xvfb in my Centos 5.7 machine to get thumbnails of websites.

I follow this [Xvfb + Firefox site](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html) and install Xvfb, firefox on my Gnome Centos 5.7.

No problem at all for installation, yet when I try to run

```
DISPLAY=:1 firefox-remote http://www.google.com/
```

I kept getting this error message

```
FreeFontPath: FPE "unix/:7100" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.
```

and I can not proceed with anything else now. Hours of hours spent and still have no clue, please help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:
http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/18/fix-freefontpath-fpe-unix7100-refcount-is-2-should-be-1-fixing/